# Assigning grades(Classes) and Subjects to teachers in Laravel (Many to Many)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Good day guys. My app have several requirements that I have to accomplish. These are listed as follows:

1. A teacher can teach many subjects
2. A teacher can teach many grades(classes)
3. A teacher cannot be assigned to a single subject in the same class twice.
4. Two(2) teachers cannot teach the same subject in the same grade(class)
5. Query out grades assigned to teachers
6. Query out subjects assigned to teachers

Base on my requirements this is how I setup my modes/database tables:

```
subject
-----------
id,
name

grades
-----------
id,
name

teachers
------------
id,
name

grade_subject
------------------
id,
grade_id,
subject_id,

subject_teacher
---------------
id,
subject_id,
teacher_id

grade_teacher
---------------
id,
grade_id,
teacher_id
```

Now for the most of what I have here will work, but the problem I'm faced with is **detecting that two teachers are not teaching the same subject in the same grade(class)**

With the above system setup I believe it will be difficult to accomplish such. 
For example how do I setup my system in such a way that avoids Two teachers teaching "Chemistry" in "Grade 12"? Will appreciate the help guys. Please let me know if I need to explain more. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! Allow me to share my view on how the database should be:

Table subjects

```
 id
 name
```

Table teachers

```
 id
 name
```

Table class

```
 id
 name
```

Now, let's say that each Teacher can teach multiple subjects

Table teacher_subject

```
 id          PK
 subject_id  FK
 teacher_id  FK
```

Let's also say, a Class has a set of subjects
so that a certain class (12th grade) can only have Chemistry, Math, etc.

Table subject_class

```
 id         PK
 class_id   FK
 subject_id FK
```

Now, we want to say:

Table teacher_subject_class

```
 subject_class_id    PK/FK
 teacher_subject_id  PK/FK
```

Meaning, something like:

'teacher_subject_id 1
subject_class_id 1'

can't be repeated (A teacher cannot be assigned to a single subject in the same class twice.)

As for the 'Two(2) teachers cannot teach the same subject in the same grade(class) rule', I'd implement the rule with logic on your app, as I can't seem to imagine (sometimes I lack imagination :( ) a database setup that would provide your concept.

Edited:
Reason : I missread and interpreted subject as a student.

Edit2: The query that you've asked

```
Select count(teacher_subject_class.teacher_subject_id) from teacher_subject_class 
inner join subject_class on subject_class.id = teacher_subject_class.subject_class_id 
inner join teacher_subject on teacher_subject.id = teacher_subject_class.teacher_subject_id 
inner join subjects on subjects.id = subject_class.subject_id 
inner join teachers on teachers.id = teacher_subject.teacher_id 
inner join class on class.id in (teacher_class.class_id, subject_class.class_id) 
where subject.name = 'Chemistry' and class.name = 'Grade 12';
```

Comment: How do you advice I implement it in the app?

Comment: Following your example, something like this query, where it returns the ammount 'teachers teaching chemistry in 12 grade', this should give you the ammount of teachers that teach Chemistry in Grade 12. so, if that number  < 1, you can execute an insert query, otherwise you can't.   Maybe i'm overthinking things but I believe this should work

Comment: Sorry but can please update your answer with the query so that I can understand a bit better

Comment: @NathanSiafa Updated